# How to get Attendees details by onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler function in outlook add-in

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I am new to the **outlook add-in**. I have configured my outlook add-in as **event-based activation** as per this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest

When I'm removing any person from meeting at that time I'm not getting their name in event. I have provided the code.

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>37cba818-c575-4ac2-85fe-332d9eae8213</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contaso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Contaso-outlook-addin" />
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started." />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help" />
  <AppDomains>
   <AppDomain>https://localhost:3000</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
    xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1"
      xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.10">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <!-- Event-based activation happens in a lightweight runtime.-->
          <Runtimes>
            <!-- HTML file including reference to or inline JavaScript event handlers.
                 This is used by Outlook on the web and Outlook on the new Mac UI. -->
            <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url">
              <!-- JavaScript file containing event handlers. This is used by Outlook on Windows. -->
              <Override type="javascript" resid="JSRuntime.Url" />
            </Runtime>
          </Runtimes>
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                  <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>

            <!-- Can configure other command surface extension points for add-in command support. -->

            <!-- Enable launching the add-in on the included events. -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
              <LaunchEvents>

                <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentSend" FunctionName="onAppointmentSendHandler"
                SendMode="PromptUser"
                />

                <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentAttendeesChanged"
                  FunctionName="onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler" />

                <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentTimeChanged"
                  FunctionName="onAppointmentTimeChangedHandler" />

                <!-- Other available events -->
                <!--
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewMessageCompose" FunctionName="onNewMessageComposeHandler" />
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewAppointmentOrganizer"
                  FunctionName="onNewAppointmentComposeHandler" />
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageAttachmentsChanged" FunctionName="onMessageAttachmentsChangedHandler"
                />
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentAttachmentsChanged"
                FunctionName="onAppointmentAttachmentsChangedHandler" />
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageRecipientsChanged" FunctionName="onMessageRecipientsChangedHandler" />
                
               
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentRecurrenceChanged"
                FunctionName="onAppointmentRecurrenceChangedHandler" />
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnInfoBarDismissClicked" FunctionName="onInfobarDismissClickedHandler" />
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageSend" FunctionName="onMessageSendHandler" SendMode="PromptUser" />
               
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageCompose" FunctionName="onMessageComposeHandler" />
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentOrganizer" FunctionName="onAppointmentOrganizerHandler" />
                -->
              </LaunchEvents>
              <!-- Identifies the runtime to be used (also referenced by the Runtime element). -->
              <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png" />
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" />
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png" />
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
          <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
          <!-- Entry needed for Outlook on Windows. -->
          <bt:Url id="JSRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/launchevent.js" />
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action" />
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contaso" />
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Contaso" />
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Open Contaso Taskpane" />
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

launchevent.js

```
function onAppointmentSendHandler(event) {
  debugger;
  setSubject(event);
}
function onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler(event) {
  setSubject(event);
}

function onAppointmentTimeChangedHandler(event) {
  setSubject(event);
}

function setSubject(event) {
  debugger;
  console.log("event", event);

}
if (Office.context.platform === Office.PlatformType.PC || Office.context.platform == null) {
  Office.actions.associate("onAppointmentSendHandler", onAppointmentSendHandler);
  Office.actions.associate("onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler", onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler);
  Office.actions.associate("onAppointmentTimeChangedHandler", onAppointmentTimeChangedHandler);
}
```

Now, when I'm removing or adding any receipt from the appointment at that time I'm not getting attendees' details. I attached the image of the function when I debugged it.
You can see in the function result I'm not getting anything.

I added the attendees from here(You can see in the image).
[image: Adding attendees]
**so, can anyone guide me to where I have done a mistake?**

[image: Function Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the actual values using the `Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees.getAsync` method call.

The [Office.RecipientsChangedFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.recipientschangedfields?view=outlook-js-preview) interface which represents `RecipientsChangedEventArgs.changedRecipientFields` object gives a basic information what field has been changed. In your scenario this is `requiredAttendees` which is set if required attendees were changed.

Be aware, you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Eugene. @ Yadav Shiv, as mentioned above the RecipientsChangedFields are boolean values to indicate the changed property. To get the values you need to make a separate call.